# What is 152³305746

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting `152³305746` as some bad data in my input file. I am trying to filter it, but have been unsuccessful in telling hive on how to detect it and filter. I am not even sure what data type it is. I am expecting `bigint` values instead of what i see here.

I have tried the below things and their various combinations which did not help skip the few bad records i have in my input:

1) 
`CAST(mycol AS string) RLIKE "^[0-9]+$"`

2)
`mycol < 2147483647`

3) 
`CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO isNumber(s string) CAST(s as BIGINT) IS NOT NULL;`

4)
`isNumber(mycol) != false`

5)
`SET mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords = 100000000;`

None of the above approaches worked. Hive fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "152³305746"
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.process(ReduceSinkOperator.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.process(FilterOperator.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:489)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "152³305746"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.primitive.ParsePrimitiveUtils.parseLong(ParsePrimitiveUtils.java:49)
        at org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.primitive.JavaStringLongObjectInspector.get(JavaStringLongObjectInspector.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe.serialize(LazyBinarySerDe.java:400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe.serializeStruct(LazyBinarySerDe.java:279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe.serializeStruct(LazyBinarySerDe.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe.serialize(LazyBinarySerDe.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.makeValueWritable(ReduceSinkOperator.java:565)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.process(ReduceSinkOperator.java:395)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: Is it possible to search your data for [unicode character U+00B3](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B3)? (`0xC2 0xB3` in utf-8)

Comment: Yes seems like its a unicode character. Do you know how to filter it?

Comment: Try `mycol RLIKE "[\xB3]"`

Comment: Why do we need to use a character class [ ] here?

Comment: You do not. `mycol RLIKE "\xB3"` should be the same- did you try it? Let me know if it worked and I'll post an answer (I don't have the ability to recreate and test it myself).